# Specify output executable name for burn bootstrapper

Tags: wix, burn

In VS2012 I created a WIX Bootstrapper project (BURN). I named the project "Bootstrapper". Now the bootstrapper works fine, but I would like to change the name of the generated file (bootstrapper.exe) in something different. I am unable to find where this outputfile name is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself. In Visual studio unload the project and change the OutputName element in the xml.

Answer (score 10):

Well, you can also do it from within VS 2012:

In Solution Explorer, right click on your Bootstrapper Project and from Context menu, click on Properties:
This should open the Properties page for your Project. You can change the output file name (and output type as well) of your Bootstrapper project

**Update:** Here is the screenshot of dialog:
[image]

Regards

Comment: Well this does not work for me. VS2012 does not show anything in the context menu for Bootstrapper, it does for a normal Wix setup project...

Comment: I'm fairly surprised to know that you can't find it. I've updated my answer with a screen shot. That might help.

Comment: I reinstalled my Visual Studio and now it works as shown in the above screenshot. Thanks..